# Double quotes on Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm running Pharo 4.0 on top Fedora 21. When I type double quotes I'm getting this:

> ˙˙

Instead of

> "

How to work around this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
By the way, typing twice single quotes do not work.

Comment: If you type a double quote somewhere else it works fine?

Comment: Yes. Ex.: " here on StackOverflow (web browser). Probably, it should has something related on how my OS is encoding. So far, my language settings is as en_US.utf8.

Comment: Is this bound to some specific tool (Such as Playground, or Nautilus, ...)? Does it also happen if you launch the image in unicode (`pharo-ui --textenc UTF-8 Pharo.image`)? I tried to replicate it in a fresh Fedora installation, but it worked as expected.

Comment: We'll need some more information to answer this. How did you install it, and what versions of vm and image are you using? It is not a common problem, so there might be interference from something else on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... I'm really up to put comments in my code...

Looking at my new keyboard's layout:
[image]

we can see that to get the proper double quotes I actually need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>¨</kbd> keys while having the <kbd>Super R</kbd> (<kbd>ALT GR</kbd>) key pressed down.

It was supposed to be the same for others applications, such as Firefox, OpenOffice Writer, but seems they were designed to leave keyboard interactions up to the operating system to supply them with **processed** keyboard characters.

Anyway, there's nothing wrong with Pharo. It's actually interpreting the keyboard as it is.

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Ah... Yes, I found a more appropriate layout which helps on shortcut motion in my keyboard.

Comment: That's an interesting keyboard layout.  Which keyboard layout is it?  It seems odd that it makes the standard keypresses - ' and " - into heavily-chorded keypresses and over-writes them with less frequently used character symbols.  Is it for desk-top publishing or some similar specialist use?

Comment: @Euan M US-International I think... I